# android NDK: Is optimizing array copy worth it?

Tags: android, android-ndk

For a school project I am creating an android app that involves streaming image data. I've finished all the requirements about a month and a half early, and am looking for ways to improve my app. One thing I heard of is using the android NDK to optimize heavily used pieces of code.

What my app does is simulate a live video coming in over a socket. I am simultaneously reading the pixel data from a UDP packet, and writing it to an int array, which I then use to update the image on the screen.

I'm trying to decide if trying to increase my frame rate (which is about 1 fps now, which is sufficient for my project) is the right path to follow for my remaining time, or if I should instead focus on adding new features.

Anyway, here is the code I am looking at:

```
public void updateBitmap(byte[] buf, int thisPacketLength, int standardOffset, int thisPacketOffset) {      
    int pixelCoord = thisPacketOffset / 3 - 1;
    for (int bufCoord = standardOffset; bufCoord < thisPacketLength; bufCoord += 3) {
        pixelCoord++;
        pixelData[pixelCoord] = 0xFF << 24 | (buf[bufCoord + 2] << 16) & 0xFFFFFF | (buf[bufCoord + 1] << 8) & 0xFFFF | buf[bufCoord] & 0xFF;           
    }
}
```

I call this function about 2000 times per second, so it definitely is the most used piece of code in my app. Any feedback on if this is worth optimizing?

Comment: In the current implementation of Dalvik, in which `GetByteArrayElements` returns a pointer to the data rather than a copy of it, a native version will speed things up if the buffer is fairly large.  If the packets are only a few dozen bytes, the overhead of switching in and out of native code may erase any gains.  If the VM's handling of primitive arrays changes, and the data is copied, you might actually make performance worse.

Comment: The packets are all 1401 bytes. Regardless of size it might be faster to access the int[] array by each byte individually, which would save a lot of shifting and bitwise operations. The bytes in byte[] buf actually directly represent the RGB values, if I could just copy them over instead of shifting that would be valuable in and of itself. This seems like something that should be doable in straight java code, but I haven't found it yet. Is it possible to have a byte[] and int[] point to the same data space?

Comment: Arrays of primitives may not overlap.  With a nio `ByteBuffer` you can "cast" the buffer to be an array of the appropriate type, and might even get the behavior you want by combining `asIntBuffer()` with a bulk get op (`IntBuffer#get(int[])`).  Make sure you set the byte order to nativeOrder (usually little endian).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just give it a try? There are many guides to creating functions using NDK, you seem to have a good grasp of the reasoning to do so and understand the implications so it should be easy to translate this small function.

Compare the two approaches, you will no doubt learn something which is always good, and it will give you something to write about if you need to write a report to go with the project.